# Create shortcut on android with Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, shortcut

I'm developing an app and want to add a feature, create an shortcut on Home screen with user image getting from web
is there any way to make it with Ionic Framework.

I know there is a way to work around with native code but I'm looking for the idea for ionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed that when you upload the apk on google's playstore that's taken care of.

Make sure it's not in debug mode, otherwise you won't be able to upload it

Comment: thanks, this function already solved by myself, making icon from web images